# What's the deal with these spikey seedy things from my blue carex grass?

Tags: planting

We are in our 2nd season with this blue carex grass, which runs the length of the house. But this year there are tall, spikey, seedy looking things coming out of them. Not all of them, but most of them. The picture tries to capture some that have it and some that don't.  Any idea? Maybe this is normal and I'm just supposed to cut them back? I've had trouble getting clear answers through generic Googling. [Location: Maryland/DC suburbs]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly normal - when the heads look white, that's the flowers - they turn brown as they start forming seed. They've flowered this year because they're old enough to do so, in their second year. You can certainly cut them  off if you don't like  the look of them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read up based on your answer, and it looks like I might actually be able to (or possibly should) cut them back 2/3... do you think that's OK this time of the year? Or wait until the fall?

Comment: That's not advice I'd follow with Carex - I'd just trim back the flowered stalks. This link mentions whether and when to cut grasses back - obviously Carex is an evergreen grass, so that's the relevant part for you https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=434